# How to access rootViewController from React-Native

Tags: objective-c, admob, react-native

I'm creating `react-native` module to access Admob.
But the GADBannerView object requires rootViewController to perform.
Do you know how to create `react-native` View/Module to do it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the native objective C code in your module, you can access the root view controller of the app as follows:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
```

Comment: Is there also a way to do this via Swift?

Comment: @BrienCrean `let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController`.